# CSS Transition background image to fade in but not animate size

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to make an image slideshow.

I am using CSS to make it transition smoothly between one image to the other, but this animates not only the fade-in transition but also the image size..

My current CSS:

```
 .slideshow{

    width:100%; 
    height:100%; 
    background-size:cover; 
    background-repeat: no-repeat; 
    background-position: center;  
    transition: background-image 5s;
    overflow:hidden;
 }
```

This fiddle shows exactly the problem: https://jsfiddle.net/raphadko/gchey1tL/

My question is.. is there a way to transition only the image fadeing, not the resizing?

Comment: I don't recall `background` transition doing that on Chrome! The effect is actually neat. Anyway, seems to be the default behaviour now in Chrome so... maybe you'll have to just use `<img>`s and change their `src` with JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get rid of the CSS transition property and do this with jQuery using the fadeOut() function:

```js
$('#changeSlide').on('click', function() {
  $('.slideshow').fadeOut('500', function() {
    $(this).css('background-image', "url('http://wallpapers.wallhaven.cc/wallpapers/full/wallhaven-210147.jpg')").fadeIn('500');
  });
})
```

```css
.slideshow {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-image: url('https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/236x/8c/e5/7a/8ce57a18e94e9f5fdc29865c7d927d6c.jpg');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="overflow:hidden; width:300px; height:300px">
  <div class="slideshow"></div>
</div>

<button id='changeSlide'>Change Slide</button>

It not only fades but it resizes too.. I want it to fade to the image already sized up to fit the slideshow div
```

**[jsFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/azizn/pzsdf3bL/2/)**